# Get Table <tr> when <td> is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How can I get the tr instead of td event?

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope'], function($scope) {
    $scope.OnRowFocused = function (event) {
        event.target.attributes.class.nodeValue = 'active';
    }
});

<table>
    <tr ng-click="OnRowFocused($event)">
        <td>
            Column 1
        <td/>
        <td>
            Column 2
        <td/>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I click on any column in the row, I always get td event instead of tr. I want to get tr event so I can highlight the focused row when the user interact with it.

Comment: instead of `target` user `$event.currentTarget`

Comment: event.currentTarget is null.

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: with event.currentTarget, i getting whole <tr> html, but how can I add css styling to <tr>?

Comment: solved by this: $(event.currentTarget).addClass('success')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do use `event.currentTarget` that will give you current element where event is happening.

```
$scope.OnRowFocused = function (event) {
    console.log('This is the correct element',event.currentTarget);
    console.log("class list", event.currentTarget[0].classList)
};
```

> I'd not recommend to go for this approach, where you are seems to be
>   manipulating DOM from controller. It should be go somewhere in
>   directive.

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5LRi7MusNCaHhXGREyPj?p=preview)

Comment: but how can I add css class to it?

Comment: solved by this: $(event.currentTarget).addClass('success')

Answer (score 0):

`event.target` is the element that received the click.

Try using `this` within the event handler - `this` is the element upon which the event is registered.